# Change in Adapter Setting Impact

Tags: pingfederate

I am new to PingFederate and don't have much knowledge on this.

We are having issue with using Basic Authentication for IOS, would you please suggest which adapter can we use for this, also does changing the adapter setting would impact all other app using same adapter setting.

let me know if you need any more details.

Thanks
Mohammed Zia

Answer (score 0):

There is a basic authentication adapter built in to the product.